# How do I Save a Variable in a File for Later Use?

Tags: jquery

I have the variable

```
var websiteTitle= "Cards";
```

in a file called variables.js. In a html file, I have a text input:

```
<input type="text" id="website-title" required>
```

The html file is called setup.html. In a jQuery called setup.js, I have the following code to handle inputs in the text box:

```
function performSetup() {
  $("#website-title").on("input", function(e) {

  });
}
```

My question is, how do I store the input in the text box into the variable in variables.js? Keep in mind the variables.js is a separate file from where the input is being handled.

Comment: You'd probably be better looking at cookies or localStorage

Comment: It needs to be stored locally on the server's filesystem @LeeTaylor

Comment: You should run a PHP server with MYSQL in order to save those values

Comment: @PhiterFernandes It's open source and needs to function via a gh-pages branch on GitHub. Besides, I'd really prefer to use jQuery; if I didn't care I'd definitely go for PHP. The repo isn't current but [here it is](https://github.com/1Achmed1/Cards). There's a more updated version [here](http://1achmed1.tk/cards/) but it's not serving via an open source repo; it's my personal server.

Comment: Then you will need to create a text file containing values, date etc... I like the material design of the project :)

Comment: @PhiterFernandes How would I create the text file? Would it not work with just a regular js file?

Thanks, BTW

Comment: JavaScript can't write to a server. You need a server-side language, like PHP, to do that.

Comment: @j08691 would it be possible with something like JSON or it not possible no matter what?

Comment: No, JSON can't write to a server-side file. You'll still need a language, running on the server, to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is more complicated than you think it is.

In order to store information obtained from a webform on a server, you will need server-side code. There is no way around it. The code would depend on your platform, it could be php, .NET, node.js, ruby on rails, and there are plenty others.

And then you can store the information in a database or a text file.

If you don't want to go through the hassle of setting up an entire server side environment, you can consider services such as parse.com, which allow you to create your own server side storage and interact with it through an API. You could use jQuery to store / retrieve the values from Parse.com, through ajax calls.

For the sake of completeness, if you're trying to save these variables on the client side, then your solutions is cookies or local storage.